# Polymer Web components and Mozilla Firefox on Windows using Webjars

Tags: firefox, compatibility, polymer-1.0, webjars

I'm trying to enable Polymer web components for Firefox so that I can navigate through my Polymer webpage on Firefox.

I tried these instructions but nothing has changed and it seems like Firefox totally ignores my components.

https://www.designedbyaturtle.co.uk/2015/how-to-enable-web-components-in-firefox-shadow-dom/

I'm also importing the `webcomponents.js` polyfills in my `index.html`.

So, what I've done is the following:

I've written the following web component `test-firefox.html` in the directory `elements`:

```
<dom-module name="test-firefox">
  <template>
    <h2>Firefox says hi too!</h2>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'test-firefox'
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

and this is my `index.html` file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
      <link rel="import" href="webjars/polymer/1.6.1/polymer.html">
      <script src="webjars/webcomponentsjs/0.7.22/webcomponents.js"></script>
      <script src="webjars/webcomponentsjs/0.7.22/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>

      <link rel="import" href="elements/test-firefox.html">

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello Firefox!</h1>
    <test-firefox></test-firefox>
  </body>
</html>`
```

As you can see, instead of the `bower_components`, I'm using the corresponding `webjars` (for `Polymer`, `webcomponents.js`, `webcomponents-lite.min.js`). I've added the dependencies for those in my `pom.xml` and they are normally installed.

So what I noticed that happens is quite strange:

- For Google Chrome, everything works perfectly fine.
- For Mozilla Firefox on Linux, the same.
- For Mozilla Firefox on Win10, the web component is not getting rendered, it is like the browser totally ignores it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can you rewrite your question?

You don't need to enable anything to get a website working in Firefox (surely you can visit https://www.polymer-project.org/ and it works for you).

If firefox "ignores" your components maybe you are missing imports for those elements.

Check this page https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements and see how `<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">` is used. You also need to import your own components this way for them to work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I rewrote my question above so that I give a bit more information. What I did not mention before and it is important is that I'm using webjars. If you have any experience/idea on that, I'd be grateful to read.

Comment: Sorry I have no experience with webjars.

In general your code looks ok - but you should be using just `webcomponents-lite.min.js` - and please remove the internal firefox flag for webcomponents from that article - it might be breaking something in your code.

Also please view console for your browser - to see if you don't get some incorrect import paths and 404's.